# Using cdrecord through popen won't eject

Tags: python, popen

So, I'm making a cd burning app and I need to eject the drive to let the user put the disk in. It's a little more complicated, but simplest case I run into is this; I can use cdrecord via the command line to eject the cd tray using this command:

```
cdrecord --eject dev='/dev/sg1'
```

which should mean that I can do the same thing with `subprocess.call`, like this:

```
subprocess.call(["cdrecord", "--eject", "dev='/dev/sg1'"])
```

however, when I do that, I get this error:

```
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

and the tray doesn't open.

This is a very similar error to one I got before when trying to run it form the command line, but I fixed that error by loading the sg kernel module.

If I just run:

```
subprocess.call(["cdrecord", "--eject"])
```

it opens the tray just fine. However, this needs to work with possibly multiple cd trays, so that won't work.

How can I get this to eject the cd correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
subprocess.call(["cdrecord", "--eject", "dev=/dev/sg1"])
```

The shell will take care of interpreting the quotes, but `cdrecord` will not.

The only reason you need the quotes in the first place is that the `dev` path might have spaces in it, causing the shell to split things into separate arguments. For example, if you type this:

```
cdrecord --eject dev=/dev/my silly cd name
```

The arguments to `cdrecord` will be `--eject`, `dev=/dev/my`, `silly`, `cd`, `name`. But if you do this:

```
cdrecord --eject dev='/dev/my silly cd name'
```

The arguments to `cdrecord` will be `--eject`, `dev=/dev/my silly cd name`.

When you're using `subprocess.call`, there's no shell to pull the arguments apart; you're passing them explicitly. So, if you do this:

```
subprocess.call(["cdrecord", "--eject", "dev=/dev/my silly cd name"])
```

The arguments to `cdrecord` will be `--eject`, `dev=/dev/my silly cd name`.

In some cases—e.g., because you get things in a hopelessly confused state in the first place (e.g., you're reading a config file that's meant to be used by your program or executed by the shell)—you really have no recourse but to run through the shell. If that happens, do this:

```
subprocess.call("cdrecord --eject dev='/dev/sg1'", shell=True)
```

But this generally isn't what you want, and it isn't what you want in this case.

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that subprocess didn't handle the quotes like the shell does. That did it, thanks.

Comment: Effectively, you're explicitly filling in the `sys.argv` array for the subprocess, and they get exactly what you type, character for character. It's a bit more complicated in some cases (especially on Windows), but that's the intention and the general rule.

Comment: Alright, I get it. That explains some weird errors I've had with popen in the past as well. Thanks, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using cdrecord but a buggy fork called "wodim" that
might be the reason for your problems.

I recommend you to use recent original software from:

ftp://ftp.berlios.de/pub/cdrecord/alpha/